# CSS: Complexed shape divide between two div's

Tags: html, css

For many hours I'm trying to find the best solution for creating a rounded horizontal separator between two sections. Below is the picture and JS Fiddle of what I'm trying to create.

The only acceptable solution that I have found so far is to use *image* with `clip-path` CSS property. But is there a simpler and more elegant solution?

[This is how divider should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVn2G.jpg)

**JsFiddle**:  [Here the Fiddle where you can experiment](https://jsfiddle.net/xdarko/t4jqhrjs/)

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.section-1,
.section-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
}

.section-1 {
  background-color: #2f4476;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-1">Section 1 content</div>
  <div class="section-2">Section 2 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it looks like you havent spent any time on this if all you have to show is 4 lines of basic HTML code.... show us your css

Comment: @DroiDev the JSfiddle is added in the question, please check.

Comment: @DroiDev, oh I spent a lot of time on this, belive me :( So far the only solution I've found is to use  clipping or masking. But there must be a simpler solution... I hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best approach to do a shape like that one is to use SVG elements to draw the curves. Here is an example of a CSS based but it's not as smooth as if it were made using SVG.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}
.section-1, .section-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  position:relative;
}

.section-1 {
  background-color: #2f4476;
  color: #fff;
}
.section-1:after{
  display:block;
  content:'';
  width:50%;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  right:-16px;
  bottom:0;
  background:#fff;
  border-top-left-radius:100px;
  transform:skew(-60deg);
}

.section-1:before{
  transform:skew(-60deg);
  display:block;
  content:'';
  width:50%;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  left:-18px;
  bottom:-20px;
  background:#2f4476;
  border-bottom-right-radius:100px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-1">Section 1 content</div>
  <div class="section-2">Section 2 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good attempt, Carlos

Comment: Thank you Carlos, I'll try to play around with this

Comment: Try applying the box shadow at the edgy corners, might give the perfect shape.

Comment: How do you get the buttons "Run code snippet" and "Copy snippet to answer"?

Comment: @PierreFrançois when creating or editing an answer one of the buttons is "add code snippet" allowing HTML, CSS and JavaScript to be added. The buttons are automatically generated for code snippets in answers.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible drawing SVG circles and rectangles from the CSS code.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 388px;
  height: 226px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 5px solid #ccc;  
}
.section-1, .section-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 50%;
}

.section-1 {
  background-color: #2f4476;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,\
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' \
      width='388' height='113'>\
      <circle cx='271' cy='205' r='120' fill='#ffffff' />\
      <rect x='260' y='85' width='128' height='28' \
        fill='#ffffff'/>\
    </svg>");
}
.section-2 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,\
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' \
      width='388' height='113'>\
      <circle cx='117' cy='-92' r='120' fill='#2f4476' />\
      <rect x='0' y='0' width='128' height='28' \
        fill='#2f4476'/>\
    </svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="section-1">Section 1 content</div>
  <div class="section-2">Section 2 content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you, Pierre. Using background images in this way is very suitable for me.